# Wordpress не запускается локальный скрипт при смене атрибута type

Tags: wordpress, mathjax

Пытаюсь подключить к wordpress MathJax и настроить его. Само подключение MathJax проблем не вызвало. Но я не могу подключить дополнительный скрипт для настройки MathJax.
Я добавляю в файл functions.php код для загрузки локального скрипта в котором находятся настройки:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'MathJaxConfiguration',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/MathJaxCfg.js', null, false, false );
```

В браузере этот скрипт загружается с атрибутом `type="text/javascript"`, но чтобы MathJax подцепил этот скрипт атрибут type= должен содержать параметр `text/x-mathjax-config`. Для замены атрибута использовал фильтр

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'filter_script_MathJax', 10, 3 );
function filter_script_MathJax( $tag, $handle, $src ){
    if ( 'MathJaxConfiguration' === $handle ) {
        return str_replace( 'text/javascript', 'text/x-mathjax-config', $tag );

    }
    return $tag;
}
```

Атрибут успешно меняется, но скрипт не выполняется. В инспекторе браузера он отображается.
Добавил в начало файла MathJaxCfg.js alert, при `type="text/javascript"` alert отрабатывает, при `text/x-mathjax-config` нет.
Как заставить все это работать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил перечитав документацию по MathJax.
В wordpress достаточно использовать конструкцию

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'MathJax', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML,http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/имя_папки_с_темой/js/MathJaxCfg.js', null, false, false );
```

Нужно было добавить `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/имя_папки_с_темой/js/MathJaxCfg.js'` - полный путь до файла настроек на сервере. А также путь до файла настроек необходимо указать в конце файла MathJaxCfg.js с помощью следующей конструкции `MathJax.Ajax.loadComplete('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/имя_вашей_темы/js/MathJaxCfg.js');`